# MATLAB rand and C++ rand()

Tags: matlab, opencv

I am trying to port a MATLAB code into C++ and found the usage of `rand` in MATLAB.

Is MATLAB's `rand` function and C++ `rand()` function same? If not, is there any inbuilt function for MATLAB's `rand` in C++ or OpenCV?

Comment: Crosspost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199376/matlab-rand-and-c-rand

Comment: What do you mean by "the same"?

Comment: same = is the implementation of rand in matlab and rand() in c++ same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a programming question, not a signal processing question - keep that in mind, and next time use the StackOverflow.

- MATLAB [**rand**](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) function returns uniformly distributed variable on interval $[0,1]$.
- C++ [**rand**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) function returns integer between `0` and `RAND_MAX`, additionally it is not very 'random' function. You would also have to normalize its output. For more info please refer here: [C++ rand() between 0 and 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878965/c-rand-between-0-and-1). Although I think that you should use the [**uniform_int_distribution**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_int_distribution/) function, providing you can take the advantage of C++11 standard.

I believe that you should use OpenCV after all, instead of playing with new standards and some tricky functions. It contains the [**RNG**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#rng) class that you can easily use for generating of uniformly distributed sequence. Here is the example:

```
RNG rng;
float r_num = rng.uniform(0, 1);
```